# Updating request params in async.each?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request

I am trying to fix my node.js crawling program.

He is a part of it:

```
var site = 'http://www.some.com/';
var startPath = '/hambaarst-1.aspx?ipp=35';
var pageNumArray = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];

async.series([
  function(callback) {
    async.each(pageNumArray, function(page, callback) {
        request(site+startPath, function(err, resp, body){
            if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                $('div.Info').find("a").each(function(){
                    var url = $(this).attr('href');
                    doctorPageUrlArray.push(url);
                }); 
            } else {
                console.log(resp.statusCode);
            }
            startPath = startPath.slice(0,11)+page+startPath.slice(-12); // HERE, I am changing start path.
            callback();
        });
    }, callback);
},
```

I need it to loop 11 times and each time change `startPath` variable:

```
startPath = startPath.slice(0,11)+page+startPath.slice(-12);
```

But instead it just crawls 11 times first page: `'/hambaarst-1.aspx?ipp=35'`.

So I guess because of node' asynchronous `startPath` doesn't updates.

**How can I fix that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var async        = require('async');
var format       = require('request');
var format       = require('util').format;

var site               = 'http://www.some.com';
var startPath          = '/hambaarst-%s.aspx?ipp=35';
var pageNumArray       = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
var doctorPageUrlArray = [];

async.each(pageNumArray, function (page, next) {
    console.log(format(site + startPath, page));

    request(format(site + startPath, page), function (err, res, body) {
        if (!err && resp.statusCode === 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);

            $('div.Info').find("a").each(function(){
                doctorPageUrlArray.push($(this).attr('href'));
            }); 
        } else {
            console.log(resp.statusCode);
        }

        next();
    });
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log(doctorPageUrlArray);
});
```